# Regarding extracting a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string Till No. S59997-RSS01 Now I need to extract the 01 from it , but the issue is that it is dynameic means

```
String TillNo =pinpadTillStore.getHwIdentifier();
```

The value S59997-RSS01 is in TillNo, that I come to know from debugging but in real time which value is coming inside TillNo , will not be known to me but the pattern of the value will be the same (S59997-RSS01) , Please advise how to extract the last two digits like(01)

Comment: @BlueBullet could you please show in post , as I not aware of it..!Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two digits will only appear at last two position, just use the `substring` method. For a more flexible way, use Regular Expression instead.

```
String TillNo = "S59997-RSS01";
System.out.println(TillNo.substring(TillNo.length() - 2));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("S[\\d]{5}-RSS([\\d]{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(TillNo);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  use the `subString` method.

Refer to [how to use subString()](http://www.java-forums.org/java-lang/7706-how-use-substring-method.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
int size = tillNo.length();
String value = tillNo.substring(size-2); // do this if size > 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

exactly, you can extract the last 2 digits using the substring method for strings like:

```
    String TillNo="S59997-RSS01";
    String substring=TillNo.substring(TillNo.length()-2,TillNo.length());
```